# ASP.Net Core Web API - ICollection not showing up in JSON resultset

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-core

I am trying to execute 3 procs in order to build the customer object and return it to the client. However, inside my api(server side) I can see the result correctly. But, unfortunately, the ICollection data is missing in the resultset (client-side)

I am using **Entity Framework** and **OData**

So, here is my model:

```
  public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string VatCode { get; set; }
        public string ChamberOfCommerceCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public decimal Discount { get; set; }
        public string CustomerManager { get; set; }
        public Guid PriceList { get; set; }
        public Guid PaymentCondition { get; set; }
       // public bool VatLiable { get; set; }
        public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
        public bool IsProspect { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuspect { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string DashboardUrl { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public ICollection<FreeFields> FreeFields { get; set; }
  //      [NotMapped]
      //  public Dictionary<string, string> UknownElements { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Contacts.Customer))]
        public ICollection<Contacts> Contact { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Addresses.Customer))]
        public ICollection<Addresses> Address { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, we have 2 ICollections in there: Contacts and Addresses.
Here the models of those two:

**Contacts** model

```
public class Contacts
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Initials { get; set; }
        public string Function { get; set; }
        [Column("Customer")]
        public Guid Customer { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public bool IsMainContact { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
```

and **Addresses**

```
 public class Addresses
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [Column("Customer")]
        public Guid Customer { get; set; }// This Property should be GUID instead of String..
        public bool IsMainAddress { get; set; }
        public string Route { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, inside my controller I fetch the data from the Stored Procedures and create the model:

```
  public IList<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            //Initialize the objects
            IList<Customer> customers = null;
            ICollection<Contacts> contacts = null;
            ICollection<Addresses> addresses = null;
            Dictionary<string, string> thisdict = null;
            //Fetch the data from stored procedures
            customers = db.Customers.FromSql("SIP_API_MONDIA_Customers_sel").ToList();
            contacts = db.Contacts.FromSql("SIP_API_MONDIA_Contacts_sel").ToList();
            addresses = db.Addresses.FromSql("SIP_API_MONDIA_Address_sel").ToList();

            //Loop through customers and add the contact and addresses when required
            foreach(var item in customers)
            {
                item.Contact = contacts.Where(x => x.Customer == item.Id).ToList();
                item.Address = addresses.Where(x => x.Customer == item.Id).ToList();
             //   item.UknownElements = thisdict;

            }
            return customers;
        }
```

Tihs works just fine, I can see with the breakpoint that the Customers object is filled. Also the Addresses and contacts are correct. But then, once I return it to the client the result is missing both ICollections..

[image]

I feel like I am missing one small detail but I fail to find it.

Comment: XML Serialization have had issues with inteface collections as member names. Maybe the same applies for json. Try changing to a more specific collection interface or a concrete class (Such as `IList<>` and `List<>`)

Comment: The problem is that I do not have access to the client(it's 3rd party) and in the docs they explicity ask for ICollection Edit: Converting to ilist to test didn't solve it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all, if you follow naming conventions you don't need to explicitly use attributes. `Key` attribute can be safely removed. `ForeignKey` attribute can be removed if you change name of properties to plural names: `Contacts` and `Addresses`. I highly encourage you to use singular names for classes and plural names for collection navigation properties (for example in One-To-Many relationship).

```
// Contact is name of class, plural name for property: Contacts
public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

If you are using OData you should build your [EDM model](http://azurecoder.net/2018/02/19/creating-odata-api-asp-net-core-2-0/#crayon-5c7ea8e05a29e158909530) (wchich you didn't show us). Also don't use stored procedures for simple `SELECT` if you have access to `DbContext`.
Your whole controller logic is unnecessary and can be replaced just with:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    return db.Customers;
}
```

So in code it can look like:

**Customer class**

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string VatCode { get; set; }
    public string ChamberOfCommerceCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public string CustomerManager { get; set; }
    public Guid PriceList { get; set; }
    public Guid PaymentCondition { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
    public bool IsProspect { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuspect { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string DashboardUrl { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FreeFields> FreeFields { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

**Contact class**

```
public class Contact
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
    public Guid Customer { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsMainContact { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    // If you want to use class reference navigation property (also called as "hard reference").
    // That can be used in "$expand" or "$select" for example.
    // Uncomment the following line:
    // public Customer Customer { get; set }
}
```

**Address class**

```
public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsMainAddress { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    // If you want to use class reference navigation property (also called as "hard reference").
    // That can be used in "$expand" or "$select" for example.
    // Uncomment the following line:
    // public Customer Customer { get; set }
}
```

Build your EDM model:

```
public class MyModelBuilder
{
    public IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);

        builder.EntitySet<Address>("Addresses")
                        .EntityType
                        .Filter() // Allow for the $filter Command
                        .Count() // Allow for the $count Command
                        .Expand() // Allow for the $expand Command
                        .OrderBy() // Allow for the $orderby Command
                        .Page() // Allow for the $top and $skip Commands
                        .Select();// Allow for the $select Command; 

        builder.EntitySet<Contact>("Contacts")
                        .EntityType
                        .Filter() // Allow for the $filter Command
                        .Count() // Allow for the $count Command
                        .Expand() // Allow for the $expand Command
                        .OrderBy() // Allow for the $orderby Command
                        .Page() // Allow for the $top and $skip Commands
                        .Select() // Allow for the $select Command
                        .Expand(); 

        builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers")
                        .EntityType
                        .Filter() // Allow for the $filter Command
                        .Count() // Allow for the $count Command
                        .Expand() // Allow for the $expand Command
                        .OrderBy() // Allow for the $orderby Command
                        .Page() // Allow for the $top and $skip Commands
                        .Select() // Allow for the $select Command
                        .Expand(); 

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Use it in **Startup**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... Other Configurations 

    services.AddOData();
    services.AddTransient<MyModelBuilder>();

    // ... MVC Service Configurations 
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, MyModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ... Other Configurations

    app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
    {
        routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoutes", "odata", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel(app.ApplicationServices));
    });
}
```

And finally create controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class CustomersController : ODataController
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public CustomersController (MyDbContext context) => _context = context;

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers() => _context.Customers;
}
```

(In code above I assume you have properly configured your `DbContext`)

Now you should be able to use `$expand` or `$select` to get, for example, all addresses of customers.

```
HTTP GET /odata/Customers?$expand=Addresses
```

Answer (score 1):

Odata doesn't support eager loading navigational properties without using expand. But you can force expand to be included in query by using an interceptor and changing url. Below is the implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.OData;

namespace ODataWebAPI.API
{
    public class EnableQueryForExpand : EnableQueryAttribute
    {
       public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           var url = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.OriginalString;
           var newUrl = ModifyUrl(url);
           actionContext.Request.RequestUri = new Uri(newUrl);
           base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
       }

       private string ModifyUrl(string url)
       {
           if (!url.Contains("expand"))
           {
               if (url.Contains("?$"))
               {
                   url = url + "&$";
               }
               else
               {
                   url = url + "?$";
               }
               url = url + "expand=Category,Supplier";
           }
           return url;
       }
   }
}
```

and you use this attribute in the controller method:

```
 [EnableQueryForExpand]
 public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue boils down to these lines:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(Contacts.Customer))]
public ICollection<Contacts> Contact { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(Addresses.Customer))]
public ICollection<Addresses> Address { get; set; }
```

`ForeignKey` is applied only to the actual foreign key property or the navigation property for that foreign key:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(Customer))]
public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

public Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

Or

```
public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(CustomerId)]
public Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

For a collection property, you need to use `InverseProperty`:

```
[InverseProperty(nameof(Contacts.Customer))]
public ICollection<Contacts> Contact { get; set; }
```

Long and short, I don't think EF is properly creating the relationships because of your error here, and therefore you're getting empty contacts and addresses lists because there's literally no related contacts or addresses.

FWIW, the use of stored procedures here is *highly* inefficient, and frankly unnecessary. A stored procedure to do a simple SELECT is no more efficient than just issuing the SELECT (there's no execution strategy to optimize if there's not multiple tables and such involved). In fact, doing it this way, you're querying all contacts and all addresses, even if only some or even none of them are related to the customers you're working with. That could be a *ton* of data you're uselessly transferring over the wire.

Comment: Hi!
I think I am still confused. Could you provide me a sample?

Comment: I gave you code samples. What is it exactly that you're confused about? Maybe we can work from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I did as you told me to do, when I do the breakpoint I can actually see the object with the addresses and contacts but it's still not returned within the json format.

Comment: It looks like you're using OData, so despite what you query, it's only going to return what was requested. You need to utilize `$expand` in your request to get the related items.

Comment: It's true that I am using OData. Thanks.. I will look into it. The client is written by a third party app and in the docs they explicity told to use OData but I've not seen the $expand function anywhere though